# Inherited TextBox missing CaretIndex property

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, inherited

I have the following code:

```
public class myTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
        if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))  // Digits are OK
        {
            // execpt if cursor is at right end
            if (this.CaretIndex == this.Text.Length)
            {
                e.Handled = true;    // throw away keypress
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I get the error:

'MyTextBoxes.myTextBox' does not contain a definition for 'CaretIndex' and no extension method 'CaretIndex'...

even though CaretIndex is a TextBox property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretindex(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed this line:

```
if (this.CaretIndex == this.Text.Length)
```

to this:

```
if ((this.Text.Length > 0) && ((this.SelectionStart + this.SelectionLength) == this.Text.Length))
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at the documentation for WPF.

The WPF `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox` control has a `CaretIndex` property.

The WinForms [`System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control does not.

Comment: Oops - missed that (wish it was more prominent in the docs.)  Question is now how to determine if the cursor is at the right end of the text...(preferably without resorting to ElementHost.)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(this.SelectionStart == this.Text.Length)
{
    e.Handled = true;    // throw away keypress
}
```

valter